# Good way Log 4j to write in different files according to module

Tags: java, log4j

Hi I have many modules in my application every module has different package. my application suppose to create different files for every module.I am doing this by following ways

```
<appender name="module1" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/var/log/camel/module1.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <param name="additivity" value="false" />
</appender>
   <logger name="com.package.module1">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="module1" />
</logger>
```

It works perfect but It needs further improvements

1. there will be so many log entry as for any module ? Can I link some properties file and provide class/ package mapping over there.
2. How could i handle common framework class as of now I m treating it as module ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any method using a properties file in the base Log4j API, but you can certainly try this programmatically in some initialization code. First create the basic definitions in XML as you have:

```
<appender name="baseModuleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/var/log/camel/${module}.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="com.package.module.base" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="baseModuleAppender" />
</logger>
```

Then do this in some Java code that gets called when your application starts up before your modules need logging:

```
String[] modules = new String[] {"module1", "module2", "module3"};
Logger baseLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.package.module.base");
DailyRollingFileAppender baseAppender = (DailyRollingFileAppender) baseLogger.getAppender("baseModuleAppender");

for (String module : modules) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.package." + module);
    logger.setLevel(baseLogger.getLevel());
    logger.setAdditivity(baseLogger.getAdditivity());

    String filename = baseAppender.getFile().replaceAll("\\$\\{module}", module);
    DailyRollingFileAppender appender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(baseAppender.getLayout(), filename, baseAppender.getDatePattern());
    appender.setAppend(baseAppender.getAppend());
    appender.setThreshold(baseAppender.getThreshold());
    logger.addAppender(appender);
}
```

You can decide how `modules` gets values however you like (through reflection, a properties file, etc.) I haven't tried this code out but I think it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch to Logback and consider using the SiftingAppender. This one splits your the logfiles the way you want.